# HTTPS URL changing from secure to non-secured in the browser interface

Tags: browser, https

We have website where we have applied SSL on subdomain, it works well in normal scenarios but in specific cases the URL shows HTTPS but it not shows secure sign.

> [image]

We are using single page application with sammy.js so URL contains `#` in it.

As soon as we hit this URL `https://app.testdomain.com/appname/App/#/Dashboards/Dashboard/Index`, the secure mark goes away and it shows like unsecured app.

What could be the possible reason?

> [image]

Comment: Click the 'i' indicator and check the console (F12) . You probably have resources that are loaded through insecure http.

Comment: yeah thanks @Anand, we found the issues, few http javascript files were there.